# Letter combinations of a phone number

Tags: c++, backtracking

Given an digit string,we need to print all letter combinations the number represents

For input "23",output should be ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"].

```
    class Solution {
public:
     char ph[10][4]={{'0','0','0','0',},{'0','0','0','0',},{'a','b','c','0'},{'d','e','f','0'},{'g','h','i','0'},{'j','k','l','0'},{'m','n','o','0'},{'p','q','r','s'},{'t','u','v','0'},{'w','x','y','z'}};
     vector<string> ans;
     void print(string digits,string st,int pos)
     {
         int i,l=digits.size();
         if(l==pos)
            {
                ans.push_back(st);
                return;
            }
        else
        {
            for(i=pos;i<l;i++)
            {
                int ch=digits[i]-'0';
                for(int j=0;j<4 && ph[ch][j]!='0';j++)
                {
                    print(digits,st+ph[ch][j],i+1);
                }
            }

        }
     }
    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        int l=digits.size();
        if(!l)
            return ans;
        print(digits,"",0);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

But I get an error for input "22",which prints 'a','b',c' additionally.What is wrong with the code?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Also for future: your title doesn't seem to relate to the question in any way. There's no mention of phone number, not to mention phone numbers don't have letters in them. The code is not explained at all so nobody has a clue what it does before parsing it all through. This is a very bad way of asking a question.

Comment: Why is the function called "print" when it doesn't print anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're both looping and recursing.

```
print("22", "", 0);
```

will recurse into

```
print("22", "a", 1);
print("22", "b", 1);
print("22", "c", 1);
print("22", "a", 2);
print("22", "b", 2);
print("22", "c", 2);
```

and your extra bits are the last three calls.

Get rid of the loop over the input digits (you're already doing that step by recursing):

```
 void print(string digits, string st, int pos)
 {
     if(digits.size() == pos)
     {
         ans.push_back(st);
     }
     else
     {
         int ch = digits[pos] - '0';
         for(int j = 0; j < 4 && ph[ch][j] != '0'; j++)
         {
             print(digits, st + ph[ch][j], pos + 1);
         }
     }
 }
```

(You also forgot to terminate some of your arrays, but that's a different issue.)